# El uso de automapper en c#

Tags: c#, automapper

soy nuevo programando y tengo una duda perdon si no puedo expersarme bien.
Estoy usando un auto mapper para poder hacer el codigo más rapido pero me encontre con un obstaculo:

Quiero editar un objeto de mi BD y a la hora de usar el automapper uso esto

```
CreateMap<HoraRequest, Hora>(); (esto esta en otra clase y esta inyectado en el constructor de la clase del controlador)


public IActionResult Edit(HoraRequest oModel)
        {
            Respuesta oRespuesta = new Respuesta();
            try
            {
               using (DBAsistenciaContext data = new DBAsistenciaContext())
                {
                    Hora oHora = data.Hora.Find(oModel.IdHora);
                    oHora = _mapper.Map<Hora>(oModel);
                    data.Entry(oHora).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                    data.SaveChanges();
                    oRespuesta.Exito = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                oRespuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
            }
            return Ok(oRespuesta);
        }
```

Si utilizo esto a la hora de editar me sale:

The instance of entity type 'Hora' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdHora'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

En cambio si hago el mappeo sin el id osea uso esto

```
CreateMap<HoraRequest, Hora>()
                .ForMember(d => d.IdHora, o => o.Ignore())
                .ForMember(d=>d.PrimerHora,o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.PrimerHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.SegundaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SegundaHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.TercerHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.TercerHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.CuartaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.CuartaHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.QuintaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.QuintaHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.SextaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SextaHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.SeptimaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SeptimaHora))
                .ForMember(d => d.OctavaHora, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.OctavaHora))
                ;
```

Me sale un error de que no pudo afectar las hilera porque no le pasa el id, pero si al principio del codigo le digo que lo encuentre con el:

```
 Hora oHora = data.Hora.Find(oModel.IdHora);
```

No entiendo porque no lo puede encontrar y editar, en cambio si lo hago uno por uno a los atributos si me edita bien

```
                   Hora oHora = data.Hora.Find(oModel.IdHora);
                    oHora.PrimerHora = oModel.PrimerHora;
                    oHora.SegundaHora = oModel.SegundaHora;
                    oHora.TercerHora = oModel.TercerHora;
                    oHora.CuartaHora = oModel.CuartaHora;
                    oHora.QuintaHora = oModel.QuintaHora;
                    oHora.SextaHora = oModel.SextaHora;
                    oHora.SeptimaHora = oModel.SeptimaHora;
                    oHora.OctavaHora = oModel.OctavaHora;
                    data.Entry(oHora).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                    data.SaveChanges();
                    oRespuesta.Exito = 1;
```

Perdón si no me explique bien, como aclare soy nuevo, me gustaria aprender a programar bien y empezar a usar el foro como se debe, ya que anteriormente he hecho pregunta y me han dicho que las hago mal, así que perdón si lo he vuelto hacer, mis disculpas

Comment: en tus dos pirmeras lineas, oHora  toma dos valores distintos... eso, esta bien?

Comment: Dato importante: Automapper NO hace código más rápido (en referencia a velocidad), sino a legibilidad y ahorro del tiempo en estar "mapeando" DTOs a Clases internas.

Comment: @gbianchi si te refieres a  Hora oHora = data.Hora.Find(oModel.IdHora); (Esto encuentra el objeto que quiero editar en la bd por el id)
                    oHora = _mapper.Map<Hora>(oModel); (este toma los datos de la resquest y lo incerta para editar) o al menos eso entendi yo en donde lo vi

Comment: ok.. no se que hace _mapper (@fredyfx ???? ) pero me suena a que son dos objetos diferentes.. no?

Comment: private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        public HoraController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            this._mapper = mapper;
        }

Comment: Pues @gbianchi lo que ocurre es simple: el mapping está apuntando a elementos diferentes, por eso es que funciona si se hace de manera manual.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando vos utilizas el find, el objeto que te devuelve esta siendo rastreado por el contexto. Esto significa que estará pendiente de cualquier cambio que hagas con ese objeto, si lo reemplazas por otro objeto tendrías conflicto como el que te ocurrió.
En tu caso tendrías que buscar sin que el contexto lo trackee, es decir, que no sea rastreado entonces podrías hacer los cambios que necesites y luego hacer el SaveChanges().
Ejemplo de codigo:

```
    public IActionResult Edit(HoraRequest oModel)
    {
        Respuesta oRespuesta = new Respuesta();
        try
        {
           using (DBAsistenciaContext data = new DBAsistenciaContext())
            {
                Hora oHora = data.Hora.Find(oModel.IdHora);
                //Aqui el objeto esta siendo rastrado pero lo seteamos como detached para que no lo rastree y le cambies los datos que necesites 
                data.Entry(oHora).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Detached;
                //Lo mapeas
                oHora = _mapper.Map<Hora>(oModel);
                //Finalmente lo seteas en estado modified y el contexto empezara a rastrearlo
                data.Entry(oHora).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
                data.SaveChanges();
                oRespuesta.Exito = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oRespuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
        }
        return Ok(oRespuesta);
    }
```

Es importante recordar que si seteas la entidad en detached y haces el saveschanges() no guardará nada porque el contexto no conoce el objeto que quiere guardar.
Espero haber sido de ayuda, Saludos!